# Must have arrived now

Tags: sentence-meaning

Please tell me if the following sentences are the same or not?

> It is ten o’clock. They must have arrived now.
>
> It is ten o’clock. They must have arrived by now.

Are they same? If not, then please tell me what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 2):

> It is ten o’clock. They must have arrived **now**.

The expectation is that "they" were scheduled to arrive *at* 10 o'clock and so should be there.
The **now** is optional in this usage.

> It is ten o’clock. They must have arrived **by now**.

The expectation is that "they" were scheduled to arrive *before* 10 o'clock and so should be there.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is saying that the "arrivees" should arrive at the time that the sentence is spoken. "By now" would mean that the people arriving should have arrived in the past (in terms of the sentence being spoken).

Answer (score 0):

The first is inferring they arrived at 10 o'clock exactly. The second means that they are arriving at around that time, or that they are possibly late.

Comment: But then what is the difference between

a) It is ten o’clock. They must have arrived now.

b) It is ten o’clock. They must arrive now.

c) It is ten o’clock. They must be arriving now.

Are the three one and the same? If not, then please tell me what the difference is.

Thank you.